# Using swift to populate NSTableView rows with a NSPopupButtonCell

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I have been trying to change one of the cells in an NSTableView to a pull-down menu, but have been unsuccessful.  I read the Apple developer documentation, but it doesn't give an example of how to use NSPopupButtonCell in a NSTableView.  I searched forums, including here, and only found one somewhat relevant example, except that it was in objective-c, so it doesn't work for my swift app.  Code for the table is here:

```
extension DeviceListViewController:NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate{
// get the number of rows for the table
func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
   return homedevices.count
}
// use the data in the homedevices array to populate the table cells
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?{
    let result  = tableView.make(withIdentifier: (tableColumn?.identifier)!, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
    if tableColumn?.identifier == "ID" {
        result.textField?.stringValue = homedevices[row].id
    } else if tableColumn?.identifier == "Name" {
        result.textField?.stringValue = homedevices[row].name
        result.imageView?.image = homedevices[row].image
    } else if tableColumn?.identifier == "Type" {
        result.textField?.stringValue = homedevices[row].type
    } else if tableColumn?.identifier == "Button" {
        result.textField?.integerValue = homedevices[row].button
    }
    return result
}
// facilitates data sorting for the table columns
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, sortDescriptorsDidChange oldDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]) {
    let dataArrayMutable = NSMutableArray(array: homedevices)
    dataArrayMutable.sort(using: tableView.sortDescriptors)
    homedevices = dataArrayMutable as! [HomeDevice]
    tableView.reloadData()
}


}
```

I really just want to be able to allow pull-down selection to change the button assigned to a particular homedevice (a simple integer), instead of having to type a number into the textfield to edit this value.  Unfortuantely, when I add the popupbuttoncell to my table in IB, all of the views for my table cells are removed.  So I may need to create the table differently.  But most of the things I have read about and tried have caused runtime errors or display an empty table.

EDIT:
Day 3:
Today I have been reading here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingViewTablesWithBindings/PopulatingView-TablesWithBindings.html
and many other places too, but I don't have rep to post any more links.

I have added a NSPopupButton in IB, but am not sure how to set the value.  I tried `result.objectValue = homedevices[row].button`, but that does not work. I suppose that I need an array controller object.  So then I tried creating an outlet for the object in my DeviceListViewController like `@IBOutlet var buttonArrayController: NSArrayController!`  I guess that I now need to somehow find a way to connect the array controller to my homedevices array.

so I looked at example code here:
https://github.com/blishen/TableViewPopup

This is in objective-C, which is not a language I am using, but maybe if I keep looking at it at various times over the course of the week, I might figure out how to make a pull-down menu.

So I am continuing to work at this, with no solution currently.

Comment: Don't use `NSPopupButtonCell`. In a view based table view just add a `NSPopButton` to the view of that column. Watch the WWDC 2011 (!) video about view based table views.

Comment: Thanks, I have watched about 30 minutes of the video.  It helps understand the view based tables, but the demo code is all Objective-C.  Is there a Swift video available?

Comment: I do notice that if I try to create an outlet to a NSPopUpButton, the build fails with error: Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

Comment: You have to subclass `NSTableCellView` to connect the outlet and I recommended the video to get the principle how to handle custom UI elements in a cell view regardless of the language. Btw: ObjC -> Swift translation is quite easy.

Comment: vadian - Thank you for your help!  I was able to create an outlet in a subclass and now the pull downs work just like they are supposed to!  Wow.  That took me a long time.  But I am excited to have learned how to do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved, thanks to @vadian.
The button is inserted as NSPopUpButton object, rather than a NSPopUpButtonCell.
Then the cell gets its own custom class, which I called ButtonCellView as a subclass of NSTableCellView.
Then the created subclass can receive an outlet from the NSPopUpButton to the custom subclass.  I can give this a selectedItem variable and create the menu here.
Then in the table view delegate, when making the table, I can just set the selectedItem of my ButtonCellView object to the value from my data array.
It works great!